# How to get a key from route module using vuex-router-sync

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I've got a little Vuex store (like below) and I use vuex-router-sync to keep it in sync. This adds a `router` module to my store, but how would I get this object out of the store as there don't seem to be any associated getters with this module?

store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import module1 from './modules/module1'
import module2 from './modules/module2'
import module3 from './modules/module3'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    module1,
    module2,
    module3
  }
})
```

main.js

```
import App from './views/App/App'
import store from './store'
import router from './router'
import { sync } from 'vuex-router-sync'

// sync router with store
sync(store, router)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

My state would look something like this:

```
{
  module1: {
    cheese: true
  },
  module2: {
    crackers: true
  },
  module3: {
    wine: true
  },
  route: {
    from: {}
    fullPath:"/path/to/cheese"
    hash:""
    meta: {}
    name:"cheese"
    params: {}
    path:"/path/to/cheese"
    query: {}
  }
}
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is add a title in my app header that updates depending on what page/view you are on.

Header.vue

```
export default {
  name: 'header',
  computed: {
    getRouteTitle () => {
      return this.$store.getters.getRouteTitle
    }
  }
}
```

Header.html

```
<header>
 <h1>{{ getRouteTitle }}</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that works quite well. vuex-router-sync fires an action to telling us that the route has changed. Within one of our existing modules you can listen out of this and make a subsequent mutation. For me this would be setting the `title` from the `router/ROUTE_CHANGED` action payload.

router.js

```
const router = [
  {
    name: 'Cheese',
    path: 'cheese',
    component: Cheese,
    meta: { title: 'Calendar', requiresAuth: true }
  },
]
```

module1.js

```
import * as types from '../mutation-types'

// Initial State
const state = {
 cheese: true,
 title: 'App'
}

// Getters
export const getters = {
  getRouteTitle: state => state.title
}

// Mutations
export const mutations = {
  'router/ROUTE_CHANGED' (state, payload) {
    state.title = payload.to.meta.title
  }
}

export default {
  getters,
  mutations,
  state
}
```

Hope that makes sense and please let me know if there is a better solution :)

******* UPDATE *********

A super easy way is just to get the `$router` instance in your component like this:

```
<h1>{{$route.name}}</h1>
```

Which would render to:

```
<h1>Cheese</h1>
```